# import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database'

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, angularfire2, angular7

I'm following a tutorial that was made a year ago and as i follow, i come across a couple of code that seems to be outdated. I 've searched a found a couple of solutions but it sadly doesn't solve mine. 
Is there therefore a newer way of writing the following code?

```
import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from "angularfire2/auth";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
```

this is the error it is printing out.

> ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable'.
>   src/app/chat-form/chat-form.component.ts(16,15): error TS2339: Property 'sendMessage' does not exist on type 'ChatService'.
>   src/app/services/chat.service.ts(2,30): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Gabriel/stack/School/HVA/JAAR 2/YOUTUBE TYPESCRIPT TUTORIAL/MyAngularApplication/We-chat/node_modules/angularfire2/database/index"' has no exported member 'FirebaseListObservable'.
>   src/app/services/chat.service.ts(4,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/Users/Gabriel/stack/School/HVA/JAAR 2/YOUTUBE TYPESCRIPT TUTORIAL/MyAngularApplication/We-chat/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'.

Comment: i think version 2,  this was my command execution npm install -- save firebase angularfire2

Comment: check my answer below, no it is called angularfire2.. has nothing to do with the version https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this:

> Module '"C:/Users/Gabriel/stack/School/HVA/JAAR 2/YOUTUBE TYPESCRIPT TUTORIAL/MyAngularApplication/We-chat/node_modules/angularfire2/database/index"' has no exported member `'FirebaseListObservable'`

It seems you are using angularFire 5.0, then you need to check the [following](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#upgrading-to-angularfire-50),
`FirebaseListObservable` was removed from the package and deprecated. You need to do the following:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

constructor(afDb : AngularFireDatabase) 
{
  afDb.list<Item>('items').valueChanges().subscribe(console.log);
}
```

---

If you still want to use the `FirebaseListObservable` then you need to import it from `'angularfire2/database-deprecated'`

Check here to see all the classes in the package `angularfire2/database-depracted`:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/tree/master/src/database-deprecated

Comment: i just found out that its been replaced with this AngularFireList https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#upgrading-to-angularfire-50

Comment: yes this is the link that I wrote in my answer.. did you try it?

Comment: i tried it and it worked, very very useful information, thanks!1

Answer (score 0):

yes u are probably using angular 5 ,it is being removed and replaced with AngularFireList
try replacing FirebaseListObservable with AngularFireList.